# How to wrap up HTML contents?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If an HTML contains say:

```
<div>1222222222222234c dssdsdf sdfsdfsdf</div>
```

How to wrap up the contents limiting to 10 characters and maybe after that we show (12222222..) two dots.

Comment: Would it not be best to use php to shorten the strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery we can do it like this

```
$(function(){
  $('div').each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length > 10) {
      var text = $(this).text();
      text = text.substr(0,10);
      $(this).text(text+"...");
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[**text-overflow: ellipsis**](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html)

But for a cross browser solution you will have to split the string and then append `.` after your desired length.

Comment: The browser support is very weak.

Comment: Got to love the CSS3 answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Since `text-overflow: ellipsis` is only "Supported by IE7-, Safari and Konqueror" - you'll probably need a javascript solution:

This is a well written one:

http://tpgblog.com/2009/12/21/threedots-the-jquery-ellipsis-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorial-how-to-auto-ellipse-text) should be what you want. [More](http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/08/ellipsis-or-truncate-with-dots-via-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

```
aaaaaaaaaa<wbr/>cccccccccc
```

Thought not on the same lines but  is one nice thing to know, this wraps the text if and only if the text is not getting fit in space. Handy for using with the messages.